# Laravel 5 Set timezone base on user settings

Tags: php, date, datetime, laravel-5

I have a user table that have a timezone column.

I want to set all of the controller function timezone based on the user setting. So when he logged in, all of the,

Ex. Chatmessage::where(....)->get();

The `created_at` * `edited_at` will be changed. I only want on GET to be changed. Not the `POST`.

I've tried `Config::set('app.timezone', Auth::user()->timezone);` it's not working, it still used the Laravel `app/config.php`

Comment: I get a feeling that it's better to do this conversion on the front end otherwise you risk messing up data in the database

Comment: @apokryfos any sample of it? I'm still newbie on Laravel

Comment: Read https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/eloquent-carbon-and-displaying-dates-in-a-users-local-timezone, there's a code sample `{{ $model->created_at->setTimezone(Auth::user()->timezone)->toDateTimeString() }}` which you can use in your `.blade.php` files when displaying data to a user without modifying the underlying database data (which should be in UTC always)

Comment: do you have any idea changing all rows without using foreach? I have this `$ProMessages = ChatMessage::with('infouser')...
->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();`

Answer (score 2):

May be not much of a clean solution, but this should work instead of config set.

`date_default_timezone_set(Auth::user()->timezone);`

Comment: this will changed on the POST method.

Answer (score 0):

I've added this on my model, I think this is the only way.

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    if(Auth::user()) {
        $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value);
        $date->setTimezone(Auth::user()->timezone ?: "UTC");

        return $date->toDateTimeString();
    } else {
        return $value;
    }
}
```